# Calculus Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, continuity

Problem:

Let $f$ be a continuous function whose domain includes $[0,1]$, such that $0 \le f(x) \le 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and such that $f(f(x)) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx > \frac34$.

Notes:
I am working on it right now so I will update this with my work.

I believe there is another question just like this one already answered.

I just want hints to try to figure it out on my own.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: The integral is exactly $1.$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Since $f$ is continuous, it doesn't skip intermediate values in the range $0\le f(x)\le 1.$ Thus, since $f(f(x))=1$ over that range, it follows that $f$ is constant over $[0,1].$

Can you finish off?